# Loading options from select work only for first item with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've just started with JavaScript/jQuery and I don't understand why my code populates the select tag only if I add steps before the click or only for the first STEP/PP's table.

I've searched and it's a common problem if you use the `id` instead of the `class` attribute, but here I've used `class`. If you have any suggestion, it would be great.

Here's my code:

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.template:last').after('<div class = "template"><table id="layout-table" WIDTH=${Globals.PRINTEDPAGE_WIDTH} BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR="#000000" CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=0 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><th>STEP</th><th>PP</th> <tr> <!-- Uso questa tabella per step e cicli/processi--><td><select class="steps3"></select></td><td><select class="pp"></select></td></tr> </table>');
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".remove").click(function() {
    $(".template:last").remove();
  });
});
$('.steps3').on("click", function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 32; i += 1) {
    $('.steps3').append($('<option>', {
      value: i,
      text: i
    }));

  }
});
$('.pp').on("click", function() {
  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i += 1) {
    $('.pp').append($('<option>', {
      value: i,
      text: i
    }));

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="template">
  <table id="layout-table" width=50% border=1 cellpadding=1 CELLSPACING=0 style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <th>STEP</th>
    <th>PP</th>
    <tr>
      <!-- Uso questa tabella per step e cicli/processi-->
      <td>
        <select class="steps3">
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="pp">
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- template -->
<p><button type="button" name="Submit" class="add">Add new step</button></p>
<p><button type="button" class="remove" name="Submit">Remove step</button></p>
```

Here the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoptys0a/

Thanks, SCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Updated]**
This is my solution. Look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarofvr/pre0yza9/37/) or here:

```js
$(function() {
    addTable();
});

function addTable(){  
    $("#containerTables").append('<table width=50% border=1 cellpadding=1 CELLSPACING=0 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><thead><tr><th>STEP</th><th>PP</th></tr><thead><tbody><tr><td><select class="select-step"></select></td><td><select class="select-process"></td></tr></tbody></table>');
  
    for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i ++) {
   $("#containerTables table:last-child .select-step").append($('<option>', {value:i, text:i}));
    }
  
    for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j ++) {
   $("#containerTables table:last-child .select-process").append($('<option>', {value:j, text:j}));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerTables"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="addTable()">
  Add new step
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="$('#containerTables table:last-child').remove()">
  Remove last step
</button>
```

Comment: nice, works also if you accidentaly remove the first table!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thecreativedev/hoptys0a/8/

```
$('.add').click(function() {
$('.template:last').after('<div class = "template"><table id="layout-table" WIDTH=${Globals.PRINTEDPAGE_WIDTH} BORDER=1 BORDERCOLOR="#000000" CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=0 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><th>STEP</th><th>PP</th> <tr> <!-- Uso questa tabella per step e cicli/processi--><td><select class="steps3"></select></td><td><select class="pp"></select></td></tr> </table>');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
//$(".remove").click(function(){
    $(".template:last").remove();
});
});

$('body').on('click', '.steps3', function() {
for (i = 1; i <= 32; i += 1) {
    $(this).append($('<option>', {value:i, text:i}));

}
});
 $('body').on('click', '.pp', function() {
  //   $('.pp').on("click", function() {
   for (i = 1; i <= 12; i += 1) {
    $(this).append($('<option>', {value:i, text:i}));

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find(".class") to get all of elements contain that class.

```
first_select();
second_select();

$('.add').click(function() {
    $('.template:last').after('<div class = "template"><table id="layout-table" WIDTH=${Globals.PRINTEDPAGE_WIDTH} BORDER=1          BORDERCOLOR="#000000" CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=0 style="margin-bottom:10px;"><th>STEP</th><th>PP</th> <tr> <!-- Uso questa tabella per step e cicli/processi--><td><select class="steps3"></select></td><td><select class="pp"></select></td></tr> </table>');

    first_select();
    second_select();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".remove").click(function(){
        $(".template:last").remove();
    });
});


function first_select() {
        for (i = 1; i <= 32; i += 1) {
        $("body").find(".steps3").append($('<option>', {value:i, text:i}));
    }
}

function second_select() {
        for (i = 1; i <= 12; i += 1) {
        $("body").find(".pp").append($('<option>', {value:i, text:i}));
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/hoptys0a/16/)